# Set server URL for an SSRS linked to report in CRM

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am working with CRM 2011 and a SSRS 2008 R2.  Each are located on different servers and are set up so that each one can be deployed from Dev servers to Production servers without causing problems to the other.

In CRM I am linking all the SSRS reports by using a URL. (Report Type: Link to Web Page). My goal is to have the SSRS URL change in CRM depending on which server CRM is deployed to.

---

**For example:**

*Dev Server*

SSRS Server - http://DevSSRSserver
CRM Report URL - http://DevSSRSserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?MyReport&rs:Command=Render

*Production Server*

SSRS Server - http://ProductionSSRSserver
CRM Report URL - http://ProductionSSRSserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?MyReport&rs:Command=Render

---

Can anybody point me into the right direction so that I can change a Report URL to a different server name depending on the server CRM is being deployed to?  I'm very new to CRM and any help at all will be greatly welcomed.

Thanks,
Shane

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple ways you can address this:

1) If the CRM/SSRS servers are in different network environments; you can just use DNS aliases in each respective environment to control what report server you want to link to.  Its not clear in your statement above if you have these server pairs in a different network or if they are on the same network and just different servers.

2) Use features of the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004) -- and write code to search for/iterate over report items in the report entity.  Replace the server portion of the URL and save the entity back to the server.

3) One thing I haven't tried before but may be appealing is to use the Export/Import features native to CRM to Export the list of reports you want to alter to Excel, edit them, and Reimport.  I'm the least sure of this approach.  I've noticed that unlike other entities, Reports has the "Download Template for Entity" option greyed out.  (Its seen under the "Import Data" button on the ribbon control)  This means you may have to do a little more work to do the import, but it may still be a better fit than the two options above.  Certainly -- its better than hand editing each individual one.

Answer (score 1):

From

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309480.aspx

1. Create a hidden parameter of type string in the report that has the name CRM_URL. For more information about adding parameters, see Use Parameters in Reports. *When the report is run, this parameter is automatically set to the Web address of Microsoft Dynamics CRM.*

Hope that helps!

Ryan